How to use react-hook-form with Tiptap editor
I want to validate my Tiptap editor using react-hook-form. The problem is that instead of validating the content length, I want to validate document lenth, i.e. the number of characters typed by user. Currently I'm validating content and its not good because the content, even when empty, contains html tags which make its length non-zero. How to do it with Tiptap editor?
